# Canvas JS - how to do random movement with acceleration

Tags: javascript, canvas, random, pixi.js

I am struggling with this particular task. I want to make animation of particles that are moving randomly (I know it can't be that much random) with kind of acceleration. I found one website that is using this effect and I am not able to replicate it myself and I spent quite a few hours researching solution, no success.

This [site](https://jakefrederick.com/#) has the desired effect. I don't know how to do the movement and acceleration to be repeating over and over.

For a moment I thought I got a clue that it's made in pixijs, but I haven't managed to do it in pixi either. All I could do was just randomly generated circular movement, but it doesn't look that well.

I would really appreacite if someone could push me in right direction.

EDIT:
[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tt0DzP2QyE9MYmRkDMOQ?p=preview) is what I got so far, as I said, it uses just circular movement.

This is just my JS file:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {

min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getLineWidth(max, min, distance) {
  if(distance < min) {return 1;}
  if(distance >= min && distance <= max) {
    return -(distance - max) / min;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function particles(numberOfParticles) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var W = canvas.width;
  var H = canvas.height;

  var x = 0, y = 0;

  //random properties of particle
  var particleProperties = [];
  for(i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
    var speed = Math.random() * (0.35 - 0.1) + 0.1; //0.1 - 0.35
    var radius = getRandomInt(100, 500); // 100 - 500
    var angle = 0;
    var direction = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    var circleCenterX = getRandomInt(250, 550); //250 - 550
    var circleCenterY = getRandomInt(150, 550); //150 - 550
    var sizeOfParticle = getRandomInt(1, 3);

    particleProperties[i] = [speed, radius, angle, direction, circleCenterX, circleCenterY, sizeOfParticle];
  }

  function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

      var coordinatesOfParticles = [];
      //object R
      for(i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
          var newX = particleProperties[i][1] * Math.cos(particleProperties[i][2] * (Math.PI/180) * particleProperties[i][3]);
          var newY = particleProperties[i][1] * Math.sin(particleProperties[i][2] * (Math.PI/180) * particleProperties[i][3]);
          x = newX + particleProperties[i][4];
          y = newY + particleProperties[i][5];
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(x, y, particleProperties[i][6], 0, 2*Math.PI);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.stroke();
          particleProperties[i][2] += particleProperties[i][0];
          coordinatesOfParticles[i] = [x, y];
      }

      for(i = 0; i < coordinatesOfParticles.length - 1; i++) {
          for(j = i + 1; j < coordinatesOfParticles.length; j++) {
              if(math.distance(coordinatesOfParticles[i], coordinatesOfParticles[j]) < 220) {
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.lineWidth = getLineWidth(220, 90, math.distance(coordinatesOfParticles[i], coordinatesOfParticles[j]));
                  ctx.moveTo(coordinatesOfParticles[i][0], coordinatesOfParticles[i][1]);
                  ctx.lineTo(coordinatesOfParticles[j][0], coordinatesOfParticles[j][1]);
                  ctx.stroke();
              }
          }
      }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
}
```

Comment: I'm quite positive that this site uses this library : https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ check out their code GitHub https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

Comment: @COLBYBROOKS I am aware of this site, but it is not what I am looking for. I am actually able to do it like the site, but I need help with the movement and acceleration. Most with the movement to be honest. particles.js has just straight movement which is not what I am trying to do, anyway thank you for answer.

Comment: One way of doing it would be multiplicating the `speed` of the particle with `Math.sin(something)` where `something` may be a function of the frames number, for example `framesNumber * Math.PI / 180`. Please add some code.

Comment: @enxaneta I added the code, maybe you will get idea how to do it or if I am doing it wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for my question, even tho it doesn't look as good as the website I mentioned, it serves the purpose. Here is my edited particles.js file. Maybe it will help somebody.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getLineWidth(max, min, distance) {
  if(distance < min) return 1;
  if(distance >= min && distance <= max) {
    return -(distance - max) / min;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function particles(numberOfParticles) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var W = canvas.width;
  var H = canvas.height;

  var x = 0, y = 0;

  //random object
  var particleProperties = [];
  for(i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
    var speed = Math.random() * (0.30 - 0.18) + 0.18; //0.1 - 0.35
    var radius = getRandomInt(100, 200); // 100 - 500
    var angle = 0;
    var direction = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    var circleCenterX = 400; //250 - 550
    var circleCenterY = getRandomInt(100, 600); //150 - 550
    var sizeOfParticle = getRandomInt(1, 3);
    var X = getRandomInt(30, 230);
    var Y = getRandomInt(290, 360);

    particleProperties[i] = [speed, radius, angle, direction, circleCenterX, circleCenterY, sizeOfParticle, X, Y];
  }

  function draw() {
      //clear rect
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

      var coordinatesOfParticles = [];
      //objekt R
      for(i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++) {
          var newX = particleProperties[i][1] * Math.cos(particleProperties[i][2] * (Math.PI/particleProperties[i][7]) * particleProperties[i][3]);
          var newY = particleProperties[i][1] * Math.tan(particleProperties[i][2] * (Math.PI/particleProperties[i][8]) * particleProperties[i][3]);
          x = newX + particleProperties[i][4];
          y = newY + particleProperties[i][5];
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(x, y, particleProperties[i][6], 0, 2*Math.PI);
          ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.stroke();
          particleProperties[i][2] += particleProperties[i][0];
          coordinatesOfParticles[i] = [x, y];
      }

      for(i = 0; i < coordinatesOfParticles.length - 1; i++) {
          for(j = i + 1; j < coordinatesOfParticles.length; j++) {
              if(math.distance(coordinatesOfParticles[i], coordinatesOfParticles[j]) < 190) {
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.lineWidth = getLineWidth(190, 90, math.distance(coordinatesOfParticles[i], coordinatesOfParticles[j]));
                  ctx.moveTo(coordinatesOfParticles[i][0], coordinatesOfParticles[i][1]);
                  ctx.lineTo(coordinatesOfParticles[j][0], coordinatesOfParticles[j][1]);
                  ctx.stroke();
              }
          }
      }
  }

  setInterval(draw, 1000/60);
}
```

Comment: I'm happy you've found your solution. For this kind of things I think simulating physics always gives a natural look. You could do it using any physics engine out there or write your own little snipped that takes a particle's current speed and mass and adds a force to it to change its direction. Every n seconds randomly change that force.

Comment: @JonasGrumann Thank you, interesting thought, I will try to do that, it might work better than this, but I want it to stay on the right (or any) side, so it just would be a simple design element that wouldnt take much performance and become laggy. Also, wouldnt eventually animation stop if I simulate it as something with mass and gravity? I am not experienced in progrograming such things, I just saw that animation and took it as a challenge for myself to create something similar.

Comment: I don't think it'll stop as long as you keep adding force to it. You could have a simple formula that adds a force towards a certain point or edge of the screen. The further away it is from the target point, the more force it adds towards it. I don't think it would become laggy because physics are mostly simple calculations such as square roots, multiplications and such, so it's something really easy for the browser

Comment: For example, look how fast this demo runs (and it has collisions turned on): http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#avalanche